# Unity - Smoothly Rotate First Person Arms to Match Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, frame-rate

I want to achieve the illusion that my Character is turning in a First Person game by having the arms shown slowly match the rotation of the Player Camera.

I'm currently struggling with this as the Arms are currently children of the Camera.

For example If im turning right, the Arm shown smoothly catches up to the Camera. like the Image below.

Any advice would be really helpful.

I have the following code, but it clearly doesn't work. This is attached to the Arms. The Proposed Rotation combines both the FirstPersonControllers X axis and the Y Camera Movement.

```
void Update()
{
    WorldSpaceRotation = transform.rotation;
    XRotation = ParentX.rotation;

    ProposedRotation = new Quaternion(ParentX.rotation.x, ParentY.rotation.y, ParentX.rotation.z, ParentX.rotation.w);


    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, ParentX.rotation, timeCount);
    timeCount = timeCount + Time.deltaTime;

}
```

[Arm Catching up to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS07q.png)

Comment: Unfortunately we will struggle to help you with your code if you dont share, please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, of course. What I do have feels miles in the wrong direction but I've updated the Question of what I do have.

Comment: Hmm things that strike me as wrong are setting the worldspacerotation, doesnt seem to have a purpose, timecount, but you never reset it, and parentX how does that relate to this object? if it is the parent it will have already moved.

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah that's the kernel of my issue, The child is always going to rotate per the parent my attempt to script into world space was to someway cause some sort of delay between the Parent and Child relationship of rotation to smooth it out later. That's why I'm here really, out of ideas. ParentX is the FirstPersonController that turns on the X axis with mouse input. ParentY is the camera, that only moves on YAxis. As per unity standard assets.

Comment: Only thing I can think if is you move the child "anti" the amount the parent moved, and then ask it to slowly catch up but that sounds painful

Comment: totally agree, thats why im here really trying to find another way of doing it.

Comment: Id probably unchild the arms and lerp them like you were trying to do

Comment: Don't make the arms a child of the camera. You're wasting cycles making Unity do unnecessary transformations for you to just undo them.

Comment: Makes sense I will explore that option, thank you troops!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up and say it works well as expected by unparenting, thanks for the advice @BugFinder